# TreeView Node Selection

Tags: c#, winforms, file, treeview, selection

I have a problem with nodes selection. Here is what I want to achieve:

```
+ [ ] Directory1
- [x] Files
       [ ] File1
       [ ] File2
       [ ] File3
       [ ] File4
       [ ] File5
       [ ] File6
```

When I click on Files (checkBox enabled), it select only Files the folder node, but instead I want it to check and select entire files while single Directory selection (i.e. By Clicking Files, it select all files contained in it). Though there are thousands of files in that directory so it is impossible to check each file manually.

I think I'm missing something here.

```
private void SetCheck(TreeNode node, bool check)
{
    foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
    {
        n.Checked = check;

        if (n.Nodes.Count != 0)
        {
            SetCheck(n, check);
        }
    }
}
```

and/or

```
private void GetCheckedFiles(TreeNode node, List<string> fileNames)
{
    if (node.Nodes.Count == 0)
    {
        if (node.Checked)
        {
            fileNames.Add(node.FullPath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
        {
            GetCheckedFiles(n, fileNames);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not setting the child checkBoxes? Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Sure you overlooked something, posting the code in your event handler that calls this code.  Setting the TreeNode.Checked property will cause the event to fire again, causing all sorts of misbehavior.  You typically need a *bool* field to prevent it from calling SetCheck() again.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva: Yes, It's WinForms.

Comment: @HansPassant: Would you please tell me what to do exactly with the code? I don't have much experience in programming. 'cuz I'm a Novice. That's why facing problems in getting your theoretical point.

Comment: I noted that you forgot to post your code for the event handler.  That was not theoretical.

Comment: Hmmm okay. Let me check event handler(s) first then will bother you again if problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code runs from the AfterCheck event, you would have to remove the handler or use a variable to prevent running the same code every time the checkmark changes for every node that gets affected by the SetCheck routine.

Example:

```
private bool ignoreCheckEvent = false;

void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e) {
  if (!ignoreCheckEvent) {
    ignoreCheckEvent = true;
    SetCheck(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    ignoreCheckEvent = false;  
  }
}
```